# starting activity for Android application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am currently developing an Android App, which integrates Google Calendar in it. As we know if we wanted to choose an activity to be the starting activity, we just add the "intent-filter" thingy. I added at my Landing Page activity but when I debug on Emulator, it will auto add the "intent-filter" at my Google Calendar activity part and comment out the one I added at my Landing Page.

This is the code at AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.dylicious.mydoctors.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dylicious.mydoctors.ViewDocActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_doc" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dylicious.mydoctors.ViewDoctorProf"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_doctor_prof" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dylicious.mydoctors.StorePatientProfile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_store_patient_profile" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dylicious.mydoctors.ViewPatientProfile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_patient_profile" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dylicious.mydoctors.AppointmentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_appointment" >
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    </activity>
```

This is the one I edited, AppointmentActivity is the Google Calendar part. I kept commenting out and delete the  part in AppointmentActivity and clean solution and etc. but it doesn't work anything. Just want to check if I had miss out anything as I'm just a newbie in the Android App Development field. Thanks a bunch in advance!

While this is the class for AppointmentActivity.java

```
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
    import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
    import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;


    import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;

    import android.accounts.AccountManager;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

public class AppointmentActivity extends Activity {

com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService;

GoogleAccountCredential credential;
private TextView mStatusText;
private TextView mResultsText;
ProgressDialog mProgress;
final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY };

/**
 * Create the main activity.
 * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance data.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    mStatusText = new TextView(this);
    mStatusText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
    mStatusText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    mStatusText.setText("Retrieving data...");
    activityLayout.addView(mStatusText);

    mResultsText = new TextView(this);
    mResultsText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
    mResultsText.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
    mResultsText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mResultsText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    activityLayout.addView(mResultsText);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setMessage("Calling Google Calendar API ...");

    setContentView(activityLayout);

    // Initialize credentials and service object.
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

    mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
            .build();
}


/**
 * Called whenever this activity is pushed to the foreground, such as after
 * a call to onCreate().
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        refreshResults();
    } else {
        mStatusText.setText("Google Play Services required: " +
                "after installing, close and relaunch this app.");
    }
}

/**
 * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
 * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
 * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
 * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
 * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
 *     activity result.
 * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
 *     activity result.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                mStatusText.setText("Account unspecified.");
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                chooseAccount();
            }
            break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

/**
 * Attempt to get a set of data from the Google Calendar API to display. If the
 * email address isn't known yet, then call chooseAccount() method so the
 * user can pick an account.
 */
private void refreshResults() {
    if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else {
        if (isDeviceOnline()) {
            mProgress.show();
            new ApiAsyncTask(this).execute();
        } else {
            mStatusText.setText("No network connection available.");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Clear any existing Google Calendar API data from the TextView and update
 * the header message; called from background threads and async tasks
 * that need to update the UI (in the UI thread).
 */
public void clearResultsText() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mStatusText.setText("Retrieving data…");
            mResultsText.setText("");
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Fill the data TextView with the given List of Strings; called from
 * background threads and async tasks that need to update the UI (in the
 * UI thread).
 * @param dataStrings a List of Strings to populate the main TextView with.
 */
public void updateResultsText(final List<String> dataStrings) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (dataStrings == null) {
                mStatusText.setText("Error retrieving data!");
            } else if (dataStrings.size() == 0) {
                mStatusText.setText("No data found.");
            } else {
                mStatusText.setText("Data retrieved using" +
                        " the Google Calendar API:");
                mResultsText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n\n", dataStrings));
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Show a status message in the list header TextView; called from background
 * threads and async tasks that need to update the UI (in the UI thread).
 * @param message a String to display in the UI header TextView.
 */
public void updateStatus(final String message) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mStatusText.setText(message);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Starts an activity in Google Play Services so the user can pick an
 * account.
 */
private void chooseAccount() {
    startActivityForResult(
            credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

/**
 * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
 * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

/**
 * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. Will
 * launch an error dialog for the user to update Google Play Services if
 * possible.
 * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
 *     date on this device; false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        return false;
    } else if (connectionStatusCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
 * or out of date.
 * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
 *     Google Play Services on this device.
 */
void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
        final int connectionStatusCode) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    connectionStatusCode,
                    AppointmentActivity.this,
                    REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

omit the `intent-filter` in your **AppointmentActivity** **AndroidManifest** file declaration. since calling action `android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"` which defines the main entry point in your application and `android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` means that the entry point should be listed in the application launcher, so you see there can't be 2 main entry points in the application.